# Is Storm version 0.9.7 still supported?

Tags: apache-storm

In the project I am working, I have to reuse a project which uses storm 0.9.7. 
I do not want to upgrade to higher version as it would need a lot of code changes I I am expected to reuse that code.
Is Storm version 0.9.7 still supported? Or is support for 0.9.7 dropped?
If Storm 0.9.7 is not supported, I may have to rewrite the code

Comment: Better ask developers directly. http://storm.apache.org/getting-help.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know development on 0.9.x has stopped. You might still be able to get answers to your questions on the user mailing list, but I'd move to a more recent release.